# how to prove the identity that $2^{ab}-1=(2^a-1)(2^{a(b-1)}+2^{a(b-2)}+.....+2^a+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am really confused.
The identity is given but I really want to know why$?$

> Show that if $2^n -1$ is a prime , then $n$ is a prime . [*Hint :* Use the identity]
>
> ### $$2^{ab} -1 = (2^a-1)\cdot(2^{a(b-1)} + 2^{a(b-2)} + \cdots + 2^a +1 )$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I'll read it right away, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following G.P :

$$1,2^a , 2^{2a} ,\cdots ,2^{a(b-2)} , 2^{a(b-1)} $$

We use the [Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas) to find it's sum :

$$S = \dfrac{1\cdot(2^{ab}-1)}{2^a-1}$$
Or

$${\color{#d05}{1+2^a + 2^{2a}+\cdots +2^{a(b-2)} + 2^{a(b-1)} = \dfrac{1\cdot(2^{ab}-1)}{2^a-1}}}$$

Rearranging this gives us the deisred result :

#### $${\color{#20f}{({2^a-1})(1+2^a + 2^{2a}+\cdots +2^{a(b-2)} + 2^{a(b-1)}) = {(2^{ab}-1)}}}$$

Answer (score 4):

You know that $x^b-1=(x-1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}+\cdots+1)$, right?! Now, replace $x$ with $2^a$.

Answer (score 2):

A different way for understanding this identity is to use binary notation.

Let us write $2^{ab}-1$ with binary digits, taking for illustration the particular case $a=3$ and $b=6$ (it works in the same way in the general case) :

$$\underbrace{111111111111111111}_{ab \ \text{digits}}=\underbrace{111}_{a \ \text{digits}} \times \underbrace{1001001001001001}_{2^{15}+2^{12}+2^{9}+2^{6}+2^{3}+1}$$